# how to set dedicated cacerts for jvm

Tags: java, unix, jvm, certificate

for the moment tomcat uses standard cacerts (/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/java) but I need to set a dedicated cacerts (eg /production) for my application. How to do it ?
thanks in advance

I tried to put cacerts in a dedicated directory (eg /production) and set configuration in catalina.sh like
JAVA_OPTS=$JAVA_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/production/cacerts -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=changeit
But it doesn't work tomcat continues to use cacerts from /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/java

Comment: *... and set configuration in catalina.sh like...* Can you please post what you did verbatim *and* in code tags?

Comment: Hi there, it's works perfectly. Thanks a lot for your prompt response / answer.